# How to prevent zsh from printing function contents when executing 'export -f'?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, zsh

I'm changing my shell from bash to zsh. But there're some scripts in my environment that will be executed when I login the server.

As an example, if I have a script like this:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
function example {
    echo "hello world"
}
export -f example
```

I will get the function content in my terminal when I login the server, like this:

```bash
function example {
    echo "hello world"
}
```

But I don't want to see it. And I know the easiest way to solve it is don't execute it, or delete it.

Is there any other method can solve it? Like disabling the output.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here? I don’t think you can export functions in Zsh.

Comment: Hi, did you ever find a solution to this?